# Unexpected regex warning "warning: character class has duplicated range"

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm getting an unexpected warning when running the following on Ruby 1.9.3:

```
"one two,three;four\rfive\nsix\r\nseven,;\r\n,;\r\neight".split(/[,|;|\r\n]+/m)
```

The warning I'm receiving is:

```
warning: character class has duplicated range: /[,|;|\r\n]+/
```

I am getting the results I expect - an array that looks like the following:

```
[
  [0] "one two",
  [1] "three",
  [2] "four",
  [3] "five",
  [4] "six",
  [5] "seven",
  [6] "eight"
]
```

What I would like to understand is what is causing the duplicated range warning? I can't achieve the same result by removing one of the three matcher options so I can't comprehend the warning.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: By the way, you don't need the `m` modifier since there is no `.` in your regex whose behaviour would be affected by it.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Indeed! Thanks. I've learnt a decent amount from this one question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you mixed up things a bit.
It currently matches any of those:

- ,
- |
- ;
- \r
- \n

And you have the pipe (|) twice in the character class.

To make the warning go away, use this instead: `/[,|;\r\n]+/`. Note: Only one pipe.

But I think what you really wanted is this: `/(,|;|\r|\n)+/` or `/[,;\r\n]+/`
This matches the following:

- ,
- ;
- \r
- \n

Comment: Ah right! The original expression that I was refactoring looked like this `/[,|;|\n|\r\n]+/m` and so I incorrectly assumed the pipes were acting like and `or`.

Comment: Inside a character class they don't act as or.

Comment: +1, but actually I think the original intention was to match `,` or `;` or `\r\n`. Your regex would also match `\r\r\r`, but I don't think that would matter in practice...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I also thought so at first, but have a look at the question. There is only `\r` between `four` and `five` and the OP expected them to be seperated.