# Regex match any character except given prefix

Tags: regex, prefix

I am looking for a regex pattern with can do as the title, it's mean with 3 given prefixs "#,@,+", the following character will be ignore until it is whitespace. Example:

> "+20 @facebook #hashtag with my love"

will return

> "with my love"

Comment: What language/environment are you running this patttern on?  And what have you tried?

Comment: You have accepted an obviously unrefined solution (with poor pattern syntax).  If you want a quality solution, please provide the information I have requested.

Comment: I have a new pattern for you, if you are using php (or more generally prce).  Can you please improve your question with more details?

Comment: Please also include 3 or more sample inputs so that readers can understand how your input text may vary.  By post a complete question, you gain the potential to receive a high quality answer and help future SO readers to fully understand your process and the answers submitted.

Comment: What is your expected result from `We are so #blessed to have @regex`?

Comment: I see that you are online.  Please answer my above questions so that I can provide a quality answer for you.

Comment: Are you reading these comments?  How about if I say this: If you post a complete and verifiable question, I will upvote your question and you can recover your lost points from downvotes.  Will you please update your question with the information that I have requested?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this in the following way

```
const regex = /[\+|\@|\#][\w\p{P}]*\s+/g;
const str = '"+20 @facebook #hashtag with my love"';
const subst = '';

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

take a look at https://regex101.com/r/K1YQQZ/1

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's work with the mention @facebook, but not for have a special character, like: "@face.book" can you help me one more time?

Comment: sure I have updated the answer , also you can find it at https://regex101.com/r/K1YQQZ/3

Comment: This is not a good pattern.  Time to read up on how to construct a character class.

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://regex101.com/r/K1YQQZ/5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12356464/2943403